# Retrieve a list of lists in one SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I have two tables (say) Person and Parent with Parent-Person being many to one relationship, so a person can have many parents, direct and indirect (grandparents etc).
Parent has foreign key personId and primary key of Person is of course, personId.

```
Person table
Id <PK>

Parent table
Id<PK>
ParentPersonId <FK into Person >

Person has rows with values PK 
1
2
3

Parent has rows with values
1, 2
1, 3
2, 3

so person 1 has parents 2, 3

I eapect to get List<Person>

[ {1, {2,3}}, {2, {3}}, {3} ]
```

I am using Spring Boot JDBC to query a MS SQL server database and I can get all parents for personId and of course, I can get a list of all persons in Person table.
But is it possible in one SQL statement to retrieve a list of all persons and within class person, a List of person Id which are the result of the join with Parent table?

Or do I have to do it in 2 steps. Get a list of persons, then query the database for the list of parents of each person?

I am trying to do something like this but it says 'syntax error'.

```
 select ID as personId (select * from Parent where personId = parentPersonId) from Person
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: SQL always return tabular data, not lists of lists; therefore your expected result will need to be post-processed in Java. Now what would it be the raw result from SQL, before preprocessing?

Comment: @TheImpaler it will take a long time, to iterate through the Java list of persons and perform a SQL query for each person, its list of parents. I left out from my question, that I also need to find the list of children for each person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data in Parent table is not recursive (this table contains a row for each ancestor, direct or indirect), you can use a simple query:

```
select per.id, par.parentPersonId 
from Person per left join Parent par 
on per.id = par.id
```

If your data is recursive (apparently not, as 3 is both parent and grandparent for 1), you need to use a recursive-CTE query. See code in my follow-up question [Is branch pruning possible for recursive cte query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59942788/is-branch-pruning-possible-for-recursive-cte-query)

Comment: Thanks, +1 I tried the query but get a flattened list of rows. Will try some more.

Comment: As pointed in comments under your question, SQL databases always return results of the query in tabular form - if you need to reshape it, it must be done on the app side. This is what ORM tools are used for, but for a single query manual transformation is perfectly viable approach