# Is branch pruning possible for recursive cte query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

This is inspired by question [Retrieve a list of lists in one SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59939806/retrieve-a-list-of-lists-in-one-sql-statement) - I have come up with a solution, but I have doubts on its efficiency.

To restate the problem:

- we have 2 Tables: `Person` and `Parent`
- `Person` contains basic data about each person
- `Parent` is a join table relating person with its parents
- each Person can have multiple parents
- we want to receive each person data with list of all their ancestors - each ancestor in its own row
- if there are no ancestors, we have only one row for that person, with null parentId

Here is the data format:

Person table

```
Id <PK>
Name
```

Parent table

```
Id<PK>
ParentPersonId <FK into Person >
```

Person has rows with values PK

```
1, 'Jim'
2, 'John'
3, 'Anna'
4, 'Peter'
```

Parent has rows with values

```
1, 2
1, 3
2, 3
3, 4
```

So person 1 has ancestors 2, 3, 4

I want the output in the following form

```
id  name    parentPersonId
--------------------------
1   Jim     2
1   Jim     3
1   Jim     4
2   John    3
2   John    4
3   Anna    4
4   Peter   (null)
```

My solution used recursive CTE query, but my fear is that it produces too many rows, as each subtree can be entered multiple times. I needed to filter out duplicates with distinct, and execution plan shows that, even with this simple data, sorting for distinct takes 50% of the time. Here is my query:

```
WITH cte_org AS 
(
    SELECT per.id, per.name, par.parentPersonId
    FROM Person per 
    LEFT JOIN Parent par ON per.id = par.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT o.id, o.name, rec.parentPersonId
    FROM Parent rec
    INNER JOIN cte_org o ON o.parentPersonId = rec.id
    WHERE rec.parentPersonId IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM cte_org
ORDER BY id, parentPersonId;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d7d62/4

**My questions:**

- can I somehow prune the already visited branches, so that recursive-CTE does not produce duplicate rows, and final distinct is not necessary
- is recursive CTE a right approach to this problem?

Comment: You're only getting duplicate rows because you have the somewhat unusual situation where someone's parent is also their grandparent so you have two paths from the child to the top of the tree via that person. For the rare (0?) number of occasions where this might occur, you're probably better off leaving distinct out of the query and dealing with it in your application.

Comment: Nick is right -- in your example data, Jim(1) is child of John(2) and Anna(3), but John(2) is also a child of Anna(3). So Jim(1) ties to Anna(3) twice, once directly as parent, and once through John as grandparent. Through these same dual lines, you also end up with Jim relating to Peter twice.

The "duplicate" data in the CTE results may be valuable to your app -- wherever there are duplicates, it indicates something likely wrong with a parent (e.g. John should not be Jim's father and brother...so either John married his own mother, or there should be 2 different Anna's (mother & daughter).

Comment: Another thing to watch out for in Recursive CTE's is circular references. For example, if you add 1 more record to Parent table with Jim as a parent of Peter (4, 1), the data creates a circle. For this reason, place a reasonable MAXRECURSION hint.

Comment: @Whitzz I must have misunderstood the data format in the original question. Indeed, there are 2 paths from 1 to 3, which makes little sense. My question stays valid in general (can we write more efficient query in case of directed acyclic graph), but does not apply for the original problem. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On PostgreSQL you can acheive that by replacing `UNION ALL` with `UNION`.
So the query looks like that:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte_org AS (
    select per.id, per.name, par.parentPersonId
    from Person per left join Parent par 
    on per.id = par.id
    UNION 
    SELECT 
        o.id, 
        o.name,
        rec.parentPersonId
    FROM 
        Parent rec
        INNER JOIN cte_org o 
            ON o.parentPersonId = rec.id
        where rec.parentPersonId is not null
)
SELECT *
FROM cte_org
ORDER BY id, parentPersonId;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/225cf4/4